# Converting dates from excel to R

Tags: r, excel, date

I have difficulty converting  dates from excel (reading from csv) to R. Help is much appreciated.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
df$date = as.Date(df$excel.date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

However, some dates get converted but some not. Here is the output of:

```
head(df$date)
[1] NA           NA           NA           "0006-01-05" NA           NA
```

the first 5 entries imported from csv file are as follows:

```
7/28/05
7/28/05
12/16/05
5/1/06
4/21/05
```

and here is the output of:

```
head(df$excel.date)
[1] 7/28/05  7/28/05  12/16/05 5/1/06   4/21/05  1/25/07 
1079 Levels: 1/1/00 1/1/02 1/1/97 1/10/96 1/10/99 1/11/04 1/11/94 1/11/96 1/11/97 1/11/98 ... 9/9/99

str(df)
.
.
$ excel.date   : Factor w/ 1079 levels "1/1/00","1/1/02",..: 869 869 288 618 561 48 710 1022 172 241 ...
```

Comment: First you should make `df$date = as.character(df$excel.date)` and after of this make `df$date = as.Date(df$excel.date,format = "%m/%d/%y"`

Comment: Tx. did that; still here is the result: df = read.csv("df.csv", as.is=TRUE)
> df$date = as.character(df$excel.date)
> head(df$date)
[1] "7/28/05"  "7/28/05"  "12/16/05" "5/1/06"   "4/21/05"  "1/25/07" 
> df$date = as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%y")
> head(df$date)
[1] NA           NA           NA           "2006-01-05" NA           NA

Comment: it should be not "%d/%m/%y" but "%m/%d/%y" - 7/28/05 is 28th July.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have the dates in your file in an unambiguous format, using full years (not just 2 last numbers). `%Y` is for *"year with century"* (see `?strptime`) but you don't seem to have century. So you can use `%y` (at your own risk, see `?strptime` again) or reformat the dates in Excel.

It is also a good idea to use `as.is=TRUE` with `read.csv` when reading in these data -- otherwise character vectors are converted to factors which can lead to unexpected results.

And on Wndows it may be easier to use RODBC to read in dates directly from `xls` or `xlsx` file.

#### (edit)

The following may give a hint:

```
> as.Date("13/04/2014", format= "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "2014-04-13"
> as.Date(factor("13/04/2014"), format= "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "2014-04-13"
> as.Date(factor("13/04/14"), format= "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "14-04-13"
> as.Date(factor("13/04/14"), format= "%d/%m/%y")
[1] "2014-04-13"
```

(So as.Date can actually take care of factors - the magick happens in `as.Date.factor` method defined as:

```
function (x, ...)  as.Date(as.character(x), ...)
```

It is not a good idea to represent dates as factors but in this case it is not a problem either. I think the problem is excel which saves your years as 2-digit numbers in a CSV file, without asking you.)

-

The `?strptime` help file says that using %y is platform specific - you can have different results on different machines. So if there's no way of going back to the source and save the csv in a better way you might use something like the following:

```
x <- c("7/28/05", "7/28/05", "12/16/05", "5/1/06", "4/21/05", "1/25/07")

repairExcelDates <- function(x, yearcol=3, fmt="%m/%d/%Y") {
 x <-  do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(x, "/"), as.numeric))
 year <- x[,yearcol]
 if(any(year>99)) stop("dont'know what to do")
 x[,yearcol] <- ifelse(year <= as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")), year+2000, year + 1900) 
 # if year <= current year then add 2000, otherwise add 1900
 x <- apply(x, 1, paste, collapse="/")
 as.Date(x, format=fmt)
 }

repairExcelDates(x)
# [1] "2005-07-28" "2005-07-28" "2005-12-16" "2006-05-01" "2005-04-21"
# [6] "2007-01-25"
```

Comment: The dates seem to be unambiguous on the excel file (4 digit year), I also added the as.id =TRUE; still here is the result: df = read.csv("df.csv", as.is=TRUE)
> df$date = as.character(df$excel.date)
> head(df$date)
[1] "7/28/05"  "7/28/05"  "12/16/05" "5/1/06"   "4/21/05"  "1/25/07" 
> df$date = as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%y")
> head(df$date)
[1] NA           NA           NA           "2006-01-05" NA           NA

Comment: check your csv file in notepad -- is the year a 4 digit number? It is probably the way excel saved the csv file ... if there were 4 digits there then R would read it. I don't know how to change the way excel saves the dates in csv format -- there might be something on it in excel help. or try RODBC  - e.g http://www.milanor.net/blog/?p=779

Comment: I ended up importing the file directly from excel (data.xlsx), thanks to the link you suggested. And now it converts the dates just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is formatted as Month/Day/Year so

```
df$date = as.Date(df$excel.date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

should be

```
df$date = as.Date(df$excel.date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```