# Convert series of numbers to date in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a .xlsx file that I read onto R. This file has one of the columns in date format (d/m/y) but for some reason it's displaying as series of numbers in the data frame on RStudio.

My question is how do I change the column to the original date format?
Here's an example of the date that's showing: `887587200` - instead of something like `12/03/1974`.

Any help to fix this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037089/converting-dates-from-excel-to-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your dates are being stored as a numeric value, likely the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. So to convert the column, you could do:

```
df$my_col <- as.Date(df$my_col / 60 / 60 / 24, origin = '1970-01-01')
```

This converts 887587200 to a date of 1998-02-16.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works. But how do I make the date to be this format dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: @HelenNeely; it reall is in that format already, it just displays differently. You can change how it looks / prints on your screen using `format` (ie `format(x, "%d/%m/%Y")` ), however, this is less useful as it converts the date format to character.